# How to clean up COM objects for an Excel Add-in that creates another Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop

I created an excel add-in that processes the active sheet and opens up another excel application and writes to another sheet.  I do not want to close excel when the program is done as this would be up to the user.  When my program runs, I can see EXCEL.exe in the task manager and when it is done, I still see it, which is what I expect and when I close EXCEL, it goes away, but I still don't know if I should be calling `ReleaseComObject` and on what variables to call it on and when.  Here is my current code:

```
public class ProcessExcel {
 Worksheet activeSheet;

ProcessExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do I need to break these into variables and/or do I need to dispose of them?
    var addIn = Globals.ThisAddIn;
    var application = addIn.Application;
    var workbook = application.ActiveWorkbook;

activeSheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

    var processor= new Processor(activeSheet, _bank);

            var processedCells = processor.Process();

            CreateExcelFile();

            GenerateOutput(processor, processedCells);
}

  private void CreateExcelFile()
        {

            var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();


            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("EXCEL could not be started");
                return;
            }

            xlApp.Visible = true;

            var workbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;

            var wb = workbooks.Add();
            xlApp.DefaultSaveFormat = xlFileFormat;

            var worksheets = wb.Worksheets;

            activeSheet = worksheets.Add();
            activeSheet.Name = "Output";


            if (activeSheet == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Worksheet could not be created");
                return;
            }

            var outputSheetColumns = activeSheet.Columns;

            foreach (var item in data.Columns)
            {
                if (item.TargetDataType != null)
                {
                    if (item.TargetDataType.ToLower() == DataType.Text.ToLower())
                    {
                        outputSheetColumns[item.TargetColumnNumber].Numberformat = NumberFormat.Text;
                    }
                }

            }


        }

  private void GenerateOutput(Processor processor, ProcessedCells processedCells)
    {
        var cells = activeSheet.Cells;

        if (data.IncludeHeader)
        {
            processor.SetHeaders(activeSheet);
        }

        foreach (var cell in processedCells.ValidCells)
        {
            var currentCell = cells[cell.RowNumber, cell.ColumnNumber];
            currentCell.Value2 = cell.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from above, I am trying am (I think) using variables for all com objects and avoiding two dots.  I do have the following method for cleanup, but not sure on which objects to use it and when:

```
 private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

I saw that `ReleaseComObject` may not be necessary and I can call:

```
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

If the user is responsible for closing the excel application, is the above necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly a bad solution that works is to kill the process

```
System.Diagnostics.Process pro = ExcelProcess.GetExcelProcess(ExcelApp);
pro.Kill();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

public static System.Diagnostics.Process GetExcelProcess(oExcel.Application excelApp)
{
    int id;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(excelApp.Hwnd, out id);
    return System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(id);
}
```

Comment: In my case, when my application ends, I want excel to be running because I want the user to close it.  I was curious if I still need to handle releasing memory if I keep excel open

Comment: This code catches the process ID that your C# code excel process uses. It kills that process. You can call many excel process to do anything. This will only kill the process that is attached to the ExcelApp object.

Comment: But I want the excel application that my C#code uses to stay open.

Comment: It should stay open if you don't close it.

Comment: But if I kill the process, won't that close it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the functions built into the interop to exit the Workbook object.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; // skip a lot of redundant typing

// declare application/workbook/worksheet objects
Excel.Application applicationObject = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbookObject;
Excel.Worksheet worksheetObject;


workbookObject = applicationObject.Open(/* lot of parameters go here */);
worksheetObject = workbookObject.Sheets["SheetName"];
DoThings(worksheetObject);

// finished working with sheet, time to close it
workbookObject.SaveAs(/* necessary parameters */);
workbookObject.Close(/* necessary parameters */);
```

After you call the Workbook.Close() method it will end the process that you created by opening